# Core Data - saving an email address

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

If I wanted to save a single string (email address), would my best option be to save it using Core Data?

Thanks

Comment: If you just need to save a single email address your best bet is to use NSUserDefaults.  Save like so: `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"email" forKey:@"UserEmailDefaultsKey"]; `then get it back:`
    NSString *email = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"UserEmailDefaultsKey"];`

Comment: thank you I appreciate the response

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you are wanting to do with it.  If this is a single string, then no.  The best option in my opinion is NSUserDefaults.  This allows you the benefit of using it in the entire application without having to write lots of code to pull it from a PList or a CD Entity.

If on the other hand, this will be a collection of email addresses then Core Data becomes much more of a valid option.

For the NSUserDefaults option, here is sample code:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setValue:@"whodat@itsme.com" forKey:@"MyEmailAddress"];
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the response and useful sample code. My follow up question, however, would be where should I cache a larger amount of data, such as a list of names (20-30 string names), or a few images? How do apps normally save images after they've been retrieved from a server? Thanks

Comment: Images can be saved as NSData objects.A list of names can be saved in an NSArray.

Comment: Is this in Core Data or NSUserDefaults though?

Comment: CoreData.  Be careful saving images though, if these are really large images and static, include them in the project and then create imageData from the file(s).  Use CoreData whenever you want to store, manipulate and retrieve data.  CD is a great thing to learn to.